# save model object using backbone

Tags: backbone.js

I'm using backbone,and have a model data like:

```
{
  "a":[{"a1":"name1","a2":"add2"},{"a1":"name3","a2":"add3"}],"c":"data1"
}
```

Now I want to edit and add the data,I set the data like:

```
        var Clone = $.extend([], model.get("a"));
        for(var i=0;i<count;i++){
            Clone[i].a1= "a"+i;
            Clone[i].a2= "b"+i;
            Clone[i].a3= "c"+i;
        }
        model.set({a:Clone});
```

but it always says that the "Clone[i]" is undefined,while when there is only one object(count=1), it can works,I don't know why.
Hope for your help,thanks.

Comment: See the following fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/K6Lk3/. It works fine, maybe the problem is somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

What is `count`? This should work:

```
_.map(Clone, function (item, index) {
    item.a1 = "a" + index;
    item.a2 = "b" + index;
    item.a3 = "c" + index;
    return item;
});
```